# Como permitir que o evento de clique seja ignorado ao clicar dentro de um elemento?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Tenho uma `div` que contem alguns elementos filhos. Gostaria de que, ao clicar na `window`, essa `div` fosse removida.

O código abaixo serviu, porém, ao clicar no conteúdo que está dentro da `div`, ela some do mesmo jeito. Como impedir que isso aconteça tanto para `div` quanto para seus elementos filhos?

Consegui fazer com que a `div` não fosse removida ao clicar nela, mas a remoção ainda é feita se clicar em um de seus filhos, o que não é o esperado.

```js
const div = document.body.firstElementChild;

function ocult(event) {
  if (event.target != div) {
    div.remove();
  }
}

window.addEventListener("click", ocult, true);
```

```css
div {
  background: #333333;
  margin: 20px;
}
p {
  background: #181818;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma opção é você adicionar um *event listener* na `div` para parar a propagação do evento de clique com [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). A `div` escutará pelos cliques em toda região que é renderizada, então pode clicar nos filhos que funcionará como esperado.

Para isso funcionar, entretanto, você precisa remover o `, true` do `window.addEventListener`. Isso porque, quando esse argumento é `true`, significa que o evento será recebido primeiro por esse listener e depois pelos outros. Portanto, com o `true`, não adiantaria colocar um listener na `div`.

**Atenção:** Se você colocou o `true` por algum motivo específico da sua aplicação, ou precisará tratar isso de um jeito melhor para poder retirá-lo, ou não deve adotar esta resposta.

```js
const div = document.body.firstElementChild;

// Adicionei o listener, apenas para parar a propagação
div.addEventListener('click', (event) => event.stopPropagation());

function ocult(event) {
  div.remove();
}

// Removi o terceiro argumento
window.addEventListener("click", ocult);
```

```css
div {
  background: #333333;
  margin: 20px;
}
p {
  background: #181818;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente reposta, tinha me esquecido disso. Esta deve ser a aceita. :-)

Answer (score 4):

A propriedade `event.target` faz referência, nos casos de eventos de clique, ao elemento que emitiu o evento em questão.

Sabendo disso, você pode utilizar a propriedade `target` para verificar se o elemento que ativou o evento cumpre uma certa condição e, a depender de seu resultado, permitir ou descartar o evento.

Trivialmente, pode-se fazer algo assim assim:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div#my-div');

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'DIV') {
    console.log('Evento descartado.');
    return;
  }
  
  div.remove();
});
```

```css
#my-div, #my-div * {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
</div>
```

Repare agora que, se você clicar na `div` (área marcada em cinza claro), ela não é mais removida. No entanto, o efeito não é descartado se clicarmos em um elemento **interno** à `div`, como um de seus elementos `p`, já que a verificação que estamos fazendo não os engloba.

Portanto, precisamos garantir que o alvo do evento não seja a `div` em questão ou um de seus filhos. Para isso, pode-se utilizar um `while` e ir verificando os parentes de `target`, assim.

Teremos, então:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div#my-div');

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // Se o alvo do evento for a div ou um de seus filhos, descarte o evento.
  if (event.target === div || isChildrenOf(event.target, div)) {
    console.log('Evento descartado.');
    return;
  }
  
  div.remove();
});

// Função que verifica se `child` é filho de `parent` na hierarquia do DOM.
function isChildrenOf(child, parent) {
  let current = child;
  while (current = current.parentElement) {
    if (current === parent) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
#my-div, #my-div * {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
  <p>Paragrafo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Maior volta, 100% explicativo e funcional, imaginei que existisse algo com um pouco menos de codigo apenas imaginei mas obrigado, se está é a unica maneira vai servir

Comment: Obs não estou julgando nem desmerecendo o codigo, está perfeito, apenas imaginei que existisse tipo um comando que fizessem isso

Comment: @Adriano, embora não exista API nativa equivalente à função `isChildrenOf`, o código pode ser reduzido com a abordagem demonstrada na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/513926/69296).